# Does data that will never change also belong into the store?

Tags: redux

Some parts of my initial state will never change during the whole lifecycle of my app. Now I wonder if this kind of data also belong into the store?

If yes:

Is there a way to put this data in the initial state when calling `createStore()`, without having an (empty) corresponding reducer function? Because since the data never changes there's no need for a reducer, but `combineReducers()` is pushing me to have one, otherwise it throws this error:

```
Unexpected key "keyName" found in initialState argument passed
to createStore. Expected to find one of the known reducer keys
instead: "otherKey1", "otherKey2". Unexpected keys will be ignored.
```

Example of what I'm looking for:

```
var dataThatWillChange = function(state, action) { /* reduce */ };

var myApp = Redux.combineReducers({
    dataThatWillChange: dataThatWillChange,
    dataThatWillNeverChange: Redux.dummyReducer // <-- something like this?
});

var store = Redux.createStore(myApp, {
    dataThatWillChange: [0, 1, 2],
    dataThatWillNeverChange: { createdBy: "me" } // <-- no need for a reducer
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you could just have a reducer that always returns the initial state, there is nothing wrong with that:

```
var initialState = { createdBy: "me" }
var dataThatWillNeverChange = function(state=initialState, action) {
  return state;
};

var store = Redux.createStore(myApp, {
    dataThatWillChange: DataThatWillChange,
    dataThatWillNeverChange: dataThatWillNeverChange
});
```

or more compactly:

```
var initialState = { createdBy: "me" }

var store = Redux.createStore(myApp, {
    dataThatWillChange: DataThatWillChange,
    dataThatWillNeverChange: () => initialState
});
```

If your constant data doesn't really belong to the "application state", you could also consider exporting it from some module and importing it whenever you need it, like

```
export default {
   createdBy: "me",
   ...
}
```